# How to keep scheduled jobs of celery worker in docker container? (django, celery, redis, docker)

Tags: django, docker, redis, celery

I deploy my django app with docker. When I update my deployment, I stop current running container and start new container with new image. I start my celery worker in the created container. (exec -> celery worker)

The problem is that the scheduled jobs (not executed yet) of celery in old container are gone since the worker gets shutdown when the container the worker is in is stopped. I understand why it happens but cannot think of how to make celery worker persistent because I think the worker is dependent on the django app.

I thought the broker keeps the job and new celery worker gets connected with the broker again so the new worker would execute the jobs, receiving them from the broker. So I kept the redis container (broker) intact, not stopping or restarting it. But the new worker did not execute the previously scheduled jobs. (I think I misunderstood how brokers work)

I think there can be two ways

1. store jobs in somewhere and get all celery workers refer to it
2. make persistent celery worker

but not sure if they are possibile. Any solutions are welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Making a celery worker survive restarts is probably less related to docker than to celery. It would somehow have to persist it's state that it can pickup on the next run. And be sure to store that state outside the container - e.g. on a mounted volume or a database.

Comment: In typical setups I've seen ([Multiple Docker containers and Celery](/a/45908901), for example) Celery runs in its own container and is backed by a store like Redis or RabbitMQ.  So long as that store is persistent you shouldn't lose jobs.  You mention "exec" in there; you shouldn't routinely need `docker exec` or similar commands.

Comment: I understood that running celery worker in separate container is needed but if so, the problem still remains when updating image. Celery should be reloaded when django app is updated and with docker container, in order to replace image the container should stop and restart. Then the previous worker is gone. Should I run celery worker not by docker container? How to replace the source code and reload celery worker, keeping the original one?